# Connect to Navision Database

Tags: odbc, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I need to connect to a .fdb file (Navision database file 2009) through C#. Can anyone explain how can I connect to this file using ODBC/NODBC?

I have tried these links but found nothing useful.

https://dynamicsuser.net/nav/f/users/21774/nodbc-connection-with-net

https://dynamicsuser.net/nav/f/developers/19641/please-help-sample-c-code-to-access-navision-4-0-using-nodbc

https://dynamicsuser.net/nav/f/developers/72463/how-to-make-a-fdb-file

https://community.dynamics.com/nav/f/microsoft-dynamics-nav-forum/33767/can-you-read-fdb-and-fbk-file-without-using-nav?pifragment-101115=1#responses

https://dynamicsuser.net/nav/f/users/61737/connect-to-fdb

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it for C#, but Python. It all boils down to the following steps:

1. Install Navision ODBC Driver which is part of the Navision 2009 installation package.
2. Set up an ODBC connection to your Navision server. (The ODBC Driver also has a connection test included)
3. Use any ODBC library to connect to the ODBC DSN created in step 2.
4. Use regular SQL syntax to communicate with the database
5. edit/p.s.: Reading your question again. I think it's possible you are lacking the server part. As far as I know, you will need a running Navision server to interact with the `fdb` file.

Comment: How is step 2 done? I installed the driver, restarted the system (because Windows ...) and found that the ODBC tool still only offers two options when adding a DSN ("SQL Server" or "SQL Server Native Client").